# Synonym for "chameleon"

Tags: nouns

I'm looking for a synonym for the term "chameleon" as applied to a person who easily fits in anywhere by altering their demeanor in a respectful positive and aware way, not with malicious intent. All ideas appreciated!

Comment: In some contexts, [**mercurial**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mercurial) *subject to **sudden or unpredictable changes** of mood or mind.* Alternatively, *versatile, adaptable, flexible, malleable,...*

Comment: Mercurial is more fitting to describe a moody, unpredictable person

Comment: @Arrow Could you provide a context please?

Comment: gregarious comes close.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. In some contexts, social butterfly would fit well. In this case, the term is being applied to a journalist who manages to fit into all kinds of situations with all kinds of people, and do his work respectfully while going fairly unnoticed.

Comment: That's not what 'social butterfly' means.

Comment: Have you checked a thesaurus? close but not exact: shapeshifter, two-faced, Zelig, politician, socially adept, malleable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A person who switches demeanor or word choice to fit into different groups at different times is [code switching](http://www.npr.org/sections/codeswitch/2013/04/08/176064688/how-code-switching-explains-the-world) in the sociological (not linguistic) sense.  From the NPR article:

> When you're attuned to the phenomenon of code-switching, you start to see it everywhere, and you begin to see the way race, ethnicity and culture plays out all over the place.

Comment: That's exactly what he does: shifts codes to blend in.

Answer (score 2):

[**"adjustable"**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adjustable) and [**"adaptable"**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adaptable) (the latter mentioned in a comment by FumbleFingers) come to mind.

> **adjustable** - able to be changed to suit particular needs [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adjustable)
>
> - "In talking about the more adjustable personality of the middle born child..."
> - "A positive, easily adjustable personality, with a streak of modesty."  [from Google Books](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22adjustable+personality%22)
>
> **adaptable** - able to change or be changed in order to fit or work better in some situation or for some purpose.
>
> - "The highly adaptable person meets the other person's needs and his own." [The Platinum Rule](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=lhQsgWMGanYC&pg=PT82&dq=%22adaptable+person%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPjJaGxJbNAhUMJiYKHajDCpUQ6AEIMzAD#v=onepage&q=%22adaptable%20person%22&f=false)
> - "An adaptable child learns to recognize the internal state of distress and hyperarousal, then finds ways to inhibit the arousal..."  [Effective Parenting for the Hard-to-Manage Child](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Fs2SAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA8&dq=%22adaptable+child%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE04DixJbNAhVDTSYKHQvHDyIQ6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=%22adaptable%20child%22&f=false)

Comment: He is indeed a great adapter

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting that you mention you don't want it to be a negative term, since most usages tend to be.

I suggest [**changeable**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/changeable)

> able to change or be changed

as a value-neutral alternative.

Comment: In this case it's positive as this journalist knows how to change his demeanor to fit in well in a wide array of situations and blend in

Answer (score 0):

A chameleon could also be a mimic:

> verb (used with object), mimicked, mimicking.
>
> 1.to imitate or copy in action, speech, etc., often playfully or derisively.
>
> 2.to imitate in a servile or unthinking way; ape.
>
> 3.to be an imitation of; simulate; resemble closely.
>
> noun
>
> 4.a person who mimics, especially a performer skilled in mimicking others.
>
> 5.a copy or imitation of something.

-Dictionary.com

Alternatively, the person could be a shape-shifter.

> one that seems able to change form or identity at will; especially :
>   a mythical figure that can assume different forms (as of animals)

-Merriam-Webster

Comment: I had thought of shape-shifter as well, as the journalist does mimic the local demeanor and behaviors, but shape-shifter has too many negative connotations!

Answer (score 0):

This is for a translation from French to English, where the French uses the term "cameleon." The client prefers to maintain "chameleon" in English as well... despite the potential negative connotations. Thank you for all the input!